# Visual Studio Text templates - Get class list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4

I am trying to make a text template which go though all classes in project and generate its partial class with additional content based on its attribute.

I would like to ask, if I am able to get a project class tree somehow, where i can read all classes and its properties and attibutes.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your [T4 template host specific](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg604090.aspx) you can access the Visual Studio object model (EnvDTE) and look at the solution, its projects and its CodeModel.

An example from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.dte.aspx) is shown below.

```
<#@ template hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<# 
 IServiceProvider serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)this.Host;
 DTE dte = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;  
#>
Number of projects in this solution: <#=  dte.Solution.Projects.Count #>
```

Once you get access to the Project you can use its [CodeModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.codemodel.aspx) and looks at the CodeElements property which has the namespaces and classes in the project.